# Dark Mode - Why/why not?

Tags: discussion

At Stack Overflow they have implemented the option to view the site in Dark Mode.

Should we not at Cross Validated have the option of a Dark Mode like they have on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I am unable to find any definition or description of what "dark mode" might be (I've read the beta notice, I've seen some of the Meta threads, etc.).  Is this just an alternative theme in which most graphical elements are dark? Or is there more to it?

Comment: Well when I visited stack overflow 2 minutes ago (30-03-2020) I was given the option to change my preferences to see the site in Dark Mode. Now the background color is dark grey (blackish) and text is white or blue. So yes just an alternative graphical scheme as far as I know. I havn't yet figured out how to reset the preferences.

Comment: It is described here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/?cb=1, where it seems only to be about graphical design.

Comment: Right: that's the beta notice.  I still find no definition and not even the beginnings of a description.  The Meta post at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/having-a-dark-theme-for-stack-exchange-sites is much more revealing and suggests we're discussing graphic design only--no modification to functionality.

Comment: Much as I'm a fan of dark mode when it's late (or early), this would create issues with the many transparent images used by users, which often become all but invisible when placed against a dark background.

Comment: @FransRodenburg that can be solved with simply setting a white background div behind images retrospectively. Just like they did migrating everything to https

Answer (score 3):

See this question in Stackoverflow: [Generating random numbers based on an inverse Gaussian distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876752/generating-random-numbers-based-on-an-inverse-gaussian-distribution). It was mentioned [in the Dark-Mode Meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396071/2874779).

Here's how it looks with Dark Mode on (the screenshot is not mine, it's from the same link in Meta I reported above):

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear there's a simple solution to the problem. In that case, I'm all for it.

Answer (score 2):

[How do I enable dark mode on other sites in the network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345902/178179):

> You can use the [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/) Chrome/Edge/Firefox/Safari extension, or natively on Chrome (chrome://flags/ : `#enable-force-dark`).

I've used dark mode on SE for years. FYI [Is the blue light emitted by computer monitors deleterious for the human eyes?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/9117/43)

---

With  chrome://flags/ : `#enable-force-dark`:

[image]

Comment: Sweet, this is nice!